# Употребление слова "наслышан"

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Можно ли употреблять слово "наслышан" в сочетании с другими, например: "Наслышан историй"? И если да, то "наслышан историй" или "наслышан историями"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Из словарей:**

НАСЛЫШАТЬСЯ, -шусь, -шишься; св. **о ком-чём и чего. Разг.** Услышать, узнать по слухам, из рассказов и т.п. о многом. Столько наслышался о вас! Всего наслышалась и нагляделась за свою жизнь.

НАСЛЫШАН, -а, -о. в функц. **сказ. о ком-чём.** Разг. По слухам, рассказам хорошо знаком с кем-, чем-л., осведомлён о ком-, чём-л. Все уже наслышаны о новой программе правительства.

**2) Варианты употребления**

**а) Обычно  используется с предлогом О/ОБ:** Я увидел его впервые, хотя много был наслышан об этом удивительном, мужественном человеке. Столько уже наслышан о вас, что не терпелось познакомиться!

**б) Другие варианты** (предлог ПРО, без предлога): Про то наслышан.  Но заочно наслышан. Это новый владыка, епископ Филофей. Небось, наслышан.

**в) В СПП в качестве опорного слова:** И я его отпустил, хотя наслышан, как там людям приходится без всяких прав.

**3. Другие падежи**

Глагол "наслышался" сочетается с Р.п.: Бакалейщик, который полагал, что **наслышался всякого** на своем веку, развел руками. Но вот варианты "наслышан историй/историями" (Р.п. или Т.п.) не встречаются в текстах.